# exit fails to set error code

Tags: c++, windows, windows-server-2008, exit-code

I have a C++ Windows program that fails to set the exit code. The program is very complex and I'm currently unable to reproduce this with a simple test case. I do know that the program calls `exit(1)` because I have a breakpoint on that line. Immediately after I step over it, the debugger (VS2010) prints `The program program.exe has exited with code 0 (0x0).` When I run it from the shell, `%ERRORLEVEL%` is also set to 0.

I use `subsystem:console` and plain old `main` (no WinMain).

This only happens on Windows Server 2008 R2, not on my Windows 8.1 laptop. I'm running the same executable on both.

I have tried to use `exit`, `_exit`, `ExitProcess`, and `return` (the offending call is in `main`), but none of those seem to have any effect. I also have tried to return other codes, also with no result.

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294947/why-cant-i-test-the-return-code-in-windows-7) but I cannot reproduce the results described in it. My program does use threads.

How can I approach debugging this issue? I'm rather baffled.

Comment: UB somewhere? Stack overwritten? Nothing else that seems odd or out of place?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is hard to tell. There may be UB somewhere but how could I find it? The stack seems OK. I understand UB is UB, but in this case we don't even have to be bound by rules of C++. WINAPI functions like `ExitProcess` just ought to work regardless (we can call them from an assembly language program). I'm absolutely sure `1` is passed to `exit` because I can step in and see the standard library code in the debugger and actually observe with the debugger how `ExitProcess(1)` is called. even on the machine instruction level. I cannot debug `ExitProcess` further though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have tried to use exit, _exit, ExitProcess, and return

You've eliminated all reasonable explanations, particularly with ExitProcess().  There is only one possibility left, you need to try TerminateProcess().  If that *still* doesn't set the exit code then you need to shove that machine out of a 4th story window.

But with the expectation that it now works.  The difference between ExitProcess() and TerminateProcess() is that the former ensures that all DLLs are notified by the termination.  Their DllMain() function gets called with fdwReason = DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.  Which gives a DLL the opportunity to do  something icky like calling Exit/TerminateProcess() itself, thus screwing up the exit code.

Finding such a DLL can be difficult if you don't have all the source code.  Could be an injected one as well, there are entirely too many around these days.  Best thing to do is to set a breakpoint on system call so you can catch it in the act, you probably want to do this regardless.

Once you step into main(), use Debug > New Breakpoint > Break at Function and enter `{,,ntdll.dll}_NtTerminateProcess@8`.  Press F5 and the debugger now stops just before the program terminates.  Look at the Call Stack to find the evil-doer.

Comment: I have tried to call TerminateProcess and it seems to work. But I'm unable to set a breakpoint to it. Are you sure the `{,,ntdll.dll}_NtTerminateProcess@8` syntax is correct? The IDE warns about invalid context, no breakpoint is set.

Comment: Hard to guess why it doesn't work on yours, I don't know anything about your VS or Windows version.  An alternative is to double-click a ntdll.dll function in the call stack, ignore the warning about not having source, then using `_NtTerminateProcess@8` as the function name.  Last gasp is to call TerminateProcess() in a little test program and single step the machine code so you can see the ntdll.dll function name on your Windows version.  Anyhoo, you learned a lot, you now know it is a DLL that is screwing this up.

Comment: @n.m. Why don't you just call FreeLibrary for some suspect DLLs, and see which one causes your process to exit? Put trace lines before and after each call so you know if FreeLibrary returns. Also didn't the VS debugger write the sequence of unloading DLLs when exiting? Maybe you could examine that.

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed the issue. There was a rogue DLL that called exit() on DLL_PROCESS_DETACH. Found with a bit of assembly debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Strange symptoms involving exit(), _exit(), ExitProcess(), and others in a multithreaded program - particularly if the symptoms vary between hosts - have a smell of a variable being modified or accessed by different threads, without synchronisation.

Looking at the other thread you linked to, it appears you are using a volatile variable to communicate between threads, but not using any form of synchronisation (for example, code which accesses the value of that variable and code that modifies that value need to cooperate via means of a critical section, mutex, or comparable construct).

That little bit of indirect evidence makes the smell even stronger.

The basic problem I suspect is that declaring a variable as volatile is neither necessary nor sufficient to ensure that variable always has values that will make sense to your program.    In particular, it is not sufficient to prevent a thread which is modifying a variable from being preempted when the modification is only partly complete, and for another thread to attempt accessing or modifying the affected variable.

If you look up some articles by Herb Sutter (particularly those concerned with thread synchronisation in his "Guru of the Week" series) you will find detailed explanations of why that is so.   Other authors also describe such things, but Sutter's articles are ones that I recall offhand.

The solution is to introduce some means of synchronisation, and for EVERY thread in your program to religiously use it before accessing or modifying variables shared between them.   This avoids the various problems (race conditions, operations being preempted partway through) that would cause symptoms like you describe.

Such problems are rarely caught by stepping through with a debugger.  The reason for that is that the symptoms are an emergent property.  Several unlikely and often independent occurrences, in disparate threads of execution, must occur together.  Debuggers do typically change the timing of events in programs, and timing is a critical consideration in the symptoms emerging.

Options include making key variables atomic (so particular operations cannot be preempted), critical sections (where the threads explicitly cooperate within a program), or mutexes (which, depending on definition, allows threads in different programs to explicitly cooperate before accessing shared memory).

Yes, this introduces a bottleneck in your program - a point where every thread must rendezvous and potentially wait for each other.   That can affect throughput of your program.    Some people advocate using volatile variables to avoid such concerns.    More often than not, the result is intermittent symptoms in long running programs like you have described in this question and the "similar question" you linked to.

It doesn't matter whether you use standard means of synchronisation (e.g. introduced in C++11) or windows specific means (WIN API functions).   The important thing is that you use a deliberate synchronisation method, rather than just making variables volatile.    Different options for synchronisation have different trade-offs, so you will need to make a decision relevant to needs of your program.

Another consideration is to signal all threads so they close cleanly, wait until they are all closed, capture their exit codes, and THEN exit the program.  It is often less error prone to do this in the thread running main() - which ultimately starts the process, so is more likely to have access to information it needs to cleanup correctly.   If another thread decides the program needs to exit, then better if it communicates that need back to main() to do it.

Comment: I don't quite understand why is it can possibly be the case. Granted unsynchronized access is it's but when calling ExitProcess C++ rules don't matter anymore, it's a WINAPI function and the only thing that matters is the parameter passed to it. And it's a constant.

Comment: I was describing concerns with synchronisation between threads, not "C++ rules".   All it needs is for one thread to do something unexpected due to inappropriate interaction with data shared with or used by another thread.

Comment: That's right, but `ExitProcess(1)` is not supposed to share any data with other threads. If synchronization isn't done right, shared data may be in invalid state, but how `ExitProcess(1)` could possibly depend on the state of any data, shared or not?

Comment: The value passed to ExitProcess() is stored somewhere. It is possible to overwrite literal values or affect the location where the value passed gets stored.   Lack of synchronisation is a multithreading contributor to what the C++ standard calls undefined behaviour.   Using win API functions doesn't introduce magic immunity to that.  Shutting down threads/process in a hard manner (like ExitProcess() or TerminateThread()) can reduce chances of clean program shutdown too.  I don't know if these are the only problems in your code, but the chances of them contributing is non-zero.

Comment: It is in theory possible to overwrite a literal integer value, but let me assure you it doesn't happen in my program (I doubt it can happen at all on X86). The literal is encoded in the instruction which is in a write-protected memory. It is impossible to overwrite it. While I'm almost sure the bug has to do with multiple threads, but I very much doubt the exact mechanism is as you describe.

Comment: Almost sure? Really?   Saying that is like describing yourself as being "almost a virgin".    The thing is, from your description, I've identified rather basic design problems in your threading design.  I'm not alone in that - people responding to the other question you linked to identified the same design concerns.   Without eliminating those design concerns, it's impossible to justify a claim that they aren't a factor in the symptoms you see.   But you do so ... and provide no evidence to justify your claim.

Comment: I don't really know what exactly you have identified. You have said there is a data race, but I see no evidence of that so far.

Comment: The other answer has identified an entirely different problem, one that has nothing to do with data races, or indeed threading. I'm still searching for the real culprit.

Comment: Really?   Common elements of both questions are threading, no synchronisation between code in one thread modifying a variable and code in another thread reading the value of that variable, no joining of threads, and program exit status that you don't expect.   That's a pretty significant set of similarities.  From your comments, I've come to believe you want to be reassured the problem results from something other than your design, so will reject any suggestions that it actually might be your design.  So, I'll drop out of this "discussion" now.   Good luck, I think you'll need it.

Comment: There is no unsynchronized access to data in the program to the best of my knowledge, and there's no requirement in any standard known to me that threads be joined at the time of program exit. The real issue was a DLL calling exit() incorrectly from DllMain with reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, just as the other answer suggested. No threads were involved at all.